# Errors when I try to add restart function to my program PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm creating a code. It works without def, but I want the code to restart on the end (print question "You wan't to restart?") and start the program from start. It work's perfectly until I add def on the top, and

```
restart=input('You want to restart?')
if restart=='YES': my_func()
```

This is my code:

```
#rektangel 
def prog():
    lengde=int(input("Hva er lengden?")) 

    bredde=int(input("Hva er bredden?"))

    areal=lengde*bredde 

    omkrets=(lengde+bredde)*2 

    

    #omkrets 

    radius=int(input("Hva er radiusen til sirkelen?"))

    pi = 3.14
    arealSirkel=pi*radius*radius

    omkretsSirkel=pi*2*radius

    svar=input("Velger du rektangel eller sirkel? \n") 

    if (svar=='Rektangel' or svar=='rektangel' or svar=='r' or svar=='R' or svar=='1'): 

        rektangel=input("Skal du finne areal eller omkrets")  

        if (rektangel=='Areal' or rektangel=='areal' or rektangel=='a' or rektangel=='A' or rektangel=='1'): 

            print("{:.2f}".format(areal),"cm")

        elif (rektangel=='Omkrets' or rektangel=='omkrets' or rektangel=='o' or rektangel=='O' or rektangel=='2'): 

            print("{:.2f}".format(omkrets),"cm") 

    elif (svar=='Sirkel' or svar=='sirkel' or svar=='s' or svar=='S' or svar=='2'): 

        sirkel=input ("Skal du finne areal eller omkrets? \n") 

        if (sirkel=='Areal' or sirkel=='areal' or sirkel=='a' or sirkel=='A' or sirkel=='1'): 

        print("{:.2f}".format(omkretsSirkel),"cm")

        elif (sirkel=='Omkrets' or sirkel=='omkrets' or sirkel=='o' or sirkel=='O' or sirkel=='2'): 
            print("{:.2f}".format(omkretsSirkel),"cm")

    else: 
        print("du skrev ugyldig verdi")


prog()
```

Sorry for not English code. It's for school project and they really wan't it in Norwegian not English (also variables...).

Thx in advanced

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Could you make it clear what is `my_func()` and what are you going to do, what errors you're facing?

Comment: You have an indentation problem in the last `if` statement. Fix this and tell us what happens when you run your code and what you would expect.

Comment: You have a function called `my_func` but you main function is called `prog`, not sure how the first part talks with the second.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 while True:
        # main program
            #rektangel 
        def prog():
            lengde=int(input("Hva er lengden?")) 
    
            bredde=int(input("Hva er bredden?"))
    
            areal=lengde*bredde 
    
            omkrets=(lengde+bredde)*2 
    
            
    
            #omkrets 
    
            radius=int(input("Hva er radiusen til sirkelen?"))
    
            pi = 3.14
            arealSirkel=pi*radius*radius
    
            omkretsSirkel=pi*2*radius
    
            svar=input("Velger du rektangel eller sirkel? \n") 
    
            if (svar=='Rektangel' or svar=='rektangel' or svar=='r' or svar=='R' or svar=='1'): 
    
                rektangel=input("Skal du finne areal eller omkrets")  
    
                if (rektangel=='Areal' or rektangel=='areal' or rektangel=='a' or rektangel=='A' or rektangel=='1'): 
    
                    print("{:.2f}".format(areal),"cm")
    
                elif (rektangel=='Omkrets' or rektangel=='omkrets' or rektangel=='o' or rektangel=='O' or rektangel=='2'): 
    
                    print("{:.2f}".format(omkrets),"cm") 
    
            elif (svar=='Sirkel' or svar=='sirkel' or svar=='s' or svar=='S' or svar=='2'): 
    
                sirkel=input ("Skal du finne areal eller omkrets? \n") 
    
                if (sirkel=='Areal' or sirkel=='areal' or sirkel=='a' or sirkel=='A' or sirkel=='1'): 
    
                    print("{:.2f}".format(omkretsSirkel),"cm")
        
                elif (sirkel=='Omkrets' or sirkel=='omkrets' or sirkel=='o' or sirkel=='O' or sirkel=='2'): 
                    print("{:.2f}".format(omkretsSirkel),"cm")
    
            else: 
                print("du skrev ugyldig verdi")
    
    
        prog()
        while True:
            answer = str(input('Run again? (y/n): '))
            if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                break
            print("invalid input.")
        if answer == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break
```